# how to get an information about processor architecture in windows 8 app

Tags: c#, windows-8, windows-runtime, windows-store-apps

I need to get an information about whether my app is running on x86, x64 or an ARM device.

is there any way to get this information in a windows 8 app via the windows runtime API.

Thanks

// Miro

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can call [`GetNativeSystemInfo`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-gb/library/windows/desktop/ms724340.aspx) from a WinRT app. That tells you the architecture of the underlying device.

Comment: You can't call GetSystemInfo(), that won't pass the Store validator.  GetNativeSystemInfo is okay.

Comment: @HansPassant You are right. I check MSDN for the "Windows Store apps" text on `GetNativeSystemInfo`. And then assumed that the same would be true for `GetSystemInfo`.

Answer (score 0):

While the app is running, go to Task Manager and select the app. Then right-click and select the file location. If it is installed in the *program files(x86)* folder, then it is a 32bit app. Otherwise it is an x64 bit app.

Comment: OP is looking to obtain the information programmatically from the inside of the executing app.